# Enlazar dos tablas sql mediante dos funciones en MVC PHP

Tags: php, poo, mvc

tengo dos funciones donde hago dos consultas y lo que quiero es unir ambas consultas pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Tengo una función obtieneIdiomas():

```
    public static function obtieneIdiomas()
{

$sql= "SELECT nombre as idiomas FROM idiomas";
$resultado=self::ejecutaConsulta($sql);
$arrayIdiomas=array();

while ($fila=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                  $arrayIdiomas[]= $fila["idiomas"];                               
             } 
        
         return $arrayIdiomas; 
}
```

Y una función obtieneCandidato():

```
public static function obtieneCandidatos()

{    
$sql2= "SELECT distinct c.dni, c.nombre, c.apellidos, c.sexo FROM candidatos c
inner join idiomas_encuesta i on c.dni=i.dni_candidato
inner join idiomas id on i.id_idioma=id.id;";

$resultado2=self::ejecutaConsulta($sql2);
$arrayCandidatos=array();

while ($fila=$resultado2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {
                  $arrayCandidatos[]=new Candidato ($fila);
             }
        
         return $arrayCandidatos; 
}
```

En el controlador llamo a estas dos funciones para construir los arrays:

```
$arrayDatosPersonas=ClaseBase::obtieneCandidatos();
$arrayIdiomasPersonas=ClaseBase::obtieneIdiomas();
```

Y hasta aquí es hasta donde he podido llegar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la consulta que debería salir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero sin que se repita los nombres de persona, es decir, en el campo Idioma de Miguel debe aparecer Frances y Chino.

He pensado que quizás haya que usar en la función obtieneCandidatos la función obtieneIdiomas pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo. Hay una tabla que comparten clave entre candidatos e idiomas e imagino que habrá que compararlos de alguna manera.

A ver si podéis echarme una mano gracias.

PD: Dándole vueltas, quizás no sea necesario utilizar la función obtenerIdiomas(), quizás se podrían hacer dos select en obtenerCandidato()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener los resultados que tú quieres en una sola consulta empleando una **función de agregación**.

No indicas qué motor de base de datos estás usando. Si empleas MySQL, dicha función es [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat). Si empleas otro motor diferente, tendrá a su disposición una función de similares características. Oracle por ejemplo dispone de [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

[En este enlace tienes un pequeño ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea9bd8/1/0) para que veas cómo funciona con unos datos de prueba, aunque también te los pego aquí a continuación.

```
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATOS (
  DNI varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  NOMBRE varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  APELLIDOS varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  SEXO char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DNI`)
);


CREATE TABLE IDIOMAS_ENCUESTA (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  DNI_CANDIDATO varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  ID_IDIOMA INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);


CREATE TABLE IDIOMAS (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPCION varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);


INSERT INTO CANDIDATOS (DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, SEXO) VALUES ('1','RICARDO','RUBIO','V');
INSERT INTO CANDIDATOS (DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDOS, SEXO) VALUES ('2','JUAN','TRUJILLO','V');

INSERT INTO IDIOMAS (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUE (1,'INGLES');
INSERT INTO IDIOMAS (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUE (2,'FRANCES');
INSERT INTO IDIOMAS (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUE (3,'ITALIANO');
INSERT INTO IDIOMAS (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUE (4,'ALEMAN');

INSERT INTO IDIOMAS_ENCUESTA (ID, DNI_CANDIDATO, ID_IDIOMA) VALUE (1,'1',1);
INSERT INTO IDIOMAS_ENCUESTA (ID, DNI_CANDIDATO, ID_IDIOMA) VALUE (2,'1',2);

INSERT INTO IDIOMAS_ENCUESTA (ID, DNI_CANDIDATO, ID_IDIOMA) VALUE (3,'2',2);
INSERT INTO IDIOMAS_ENCUESTA (ID, DNI_CANDIDATO, ID_IDIOMA) VALUE (4,'2',3);
INSERT INTO IDIOMAS_ENCUESTA (ID, DNI_CANDIDATO, ID_IDIOMA) VALUE (5,'2',4);
```

Modificando un poco la consulta que incluyes, obtenemos el resultado esperado

```
SELECT C.DNI, 
       C.NOMBRE, 
       C.APELLIDOS, 
       C.SEXO, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(ID.DESCRIPCION SEPARATOR ',') AS LISTA_IDIOMAS
FROM candidatos c
inner join idiomas_encuesta i on c.dni = i.dni_candidato
inner join idiomas id on i.id_idioma = id.id
GROUP BY C.DNI, C.NOMBRE, C.APELLIDOS, C.SEXO;
```

Resultado con mi juego de datos reducido

```
DNI NOMBRE  APELLIDOS   SEXO    LISTA_IDIOMAS
1   RICARDO RUBIO       V       FRANCES,INGLES
2   JUAN    TRUJILLO    V       ALEMAN,ITALIANO,FRANCES
```

La próxima vez procura añadir a tu pregunta la estructura de las tablas (CREATE) y algún juego de datos de prueba (INSERT) de forma que quien desee ayudarte pueda copiarlos y añadirlos a su respuesta. Siempre estás a tiempo de editar e incluir esta información.

**BONUS**
Si quieres que la lista de idiomas te salga ordenada, tienes que aplicar un ORDER antes de aplicar la agregación. Aquí te pongo otra consulta de ejemplo con los datos ordenados de otra forma.

```
SELECT APELLIDOS, 
       NOMBRE, 
       DNI, 
       SEXO, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(IDIOMA SEPARATOR ',') AS LISTA_IDIOMAS
FROM (
SELECT C.APELLIDOS AS APELLIDOS, 
       C.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE, 
       C.DNI AS DNI, 
       C.SEXO AS SEXO, 
       ID.DESCRIPCION AS IDIOMA
FROM candidatos c
inner join idiomas_encuesta i on c.dni = i.dni_candidato
inner join idiomas id on i.id_idioma = id.id
ORDER BY IDIOMA, C.APELLIDOS, C.NOMBRE
) AS A
GROUP BY APELLIDOS, NOMBRE, DNI, SEXO;
```

Resultado bonus

```
APELLIDOS   NOMBRE  DNI SEXO    LISTA_IDIOMAS
RUBIO       RICARDO 1   V       INGLES,FRANCES
TRUJILLO    JUAN    2   V       ITALIANO,FRANCES,ALEMAN
```